# Seemingly unrelated regression and multivariate Regression

Tags: modeling, least-squares, multivariate-regression

I have a problem with an linear regression model in which I have 2 dependent variables. Both are highly correlated with each other and should both be explained by the linear model

`y = Xbeta + u`

I´am asking myself if I can perform a seemingly unrelated regression (SUR)  or a multivariate regression model because I am not sure about the differences between this two approaches.

I would be glad if someone can help me in this case.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seemingly_unrelated_regressions) SUR is equivalent to the equation-by-equation OLS under the following two conditions:

```
i. When there are no cross-equation correlations between the error terms

ii. When each equation contains exactly the same set of regressors.
```

That being said, if your model and data don't satisfy above two cases, then you can proceed with the SUR.