# Seemingly unrelated regression and OLS

Tags: least-squares

[It's been said that](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66533/seemingly-unrelated-regression-and-multivariate-regression) SUR is equivalent to the equation-by-equation OLS:

> i. When there are no cross-equation correlations between the error terms.
>   ii. When each equation contains exactly the same set of regressors.

I would like to confirm whether each condition is necessary or sufficient, namely the second condition. In [4.5.1 Seemingly Unrelated Regression](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/webbooks/reg/chapter4/statareg4.htm), the author uses an example of SUR with equations that each use the same set of regressors, which seems to violate (ii) if each condition is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The answer at your first link provides a link to Wikipedia as support for its statement.

If you read the relevant portion of the Wikipedia article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seemingly_unrelated_regressions#Equivalence_to_OLS), it is quite explicit that the two cases are separate. It gives a justification in each case.

That is, either condition is sufficient on its own.

Comment: Please note: the wiki entry isn't 100% accurate. If you read the original Zellner paper from 1962 either condition is sufficient on its own for SUR to be equivalent to equation-by-equation Maximum Likelihood estimation (page 351 of: http://www.indiana.edu/~phinite/S681/Zellner.pdf). [But note that the MLE estimates will be equivalent to OLS estimates under the assumption of normal errors, and thus to the SUR estimates].